# Cannot find log4j.properties when using log4j with java 7

Tags: java, log4j, java-7

I have built an executable jar and using log4j with it.First I used Java6 to build it,and It was running perfect.But when I updated JDK to version 1.7 and built my project again.It seems cannot find the `log4j.properties` file since I cannot find my log files and the log format in the console is wrong too.

Comment: have you find out the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you extracted your .JAR file to ensure that "log4j.properties" exists in the root folder?  Are you sure that it is named correctly (it is named "log4j.perperties" in your question).

Troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Run app with "-Dlog4j.debug" flag and observe log4j output
2. Run project without "-jar" to avoid jar packaging issues (e.g. "java -cp ./xxx.jar com.pkg.AppClass")
3. Examine encoding of the log4j.properties file
4. Attempt manual initialization of log4j within your application, first with an external file then with the internal classpath file

I do not see any obvious JDK7 & log4j conflicts with a few minutes of googling, so it doesn't look like a "known JDK7 issue" to me.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.Yes,I extracted the jar and find the file with right name.And it works well when I using Java6

Comment: Try running with "-Dlog4j.debug" and see if that sheds light on how log4j initializes.  There could be a number of issues causing log4j to not find or be capable of reading the standard file.  I would then recommend trying to manually initialize log4j, followed by ensuring that your log4j.properties file is plain text with a standard encoding (i.e. ASCII), although I'm not familiar with how log4j behaves with other encodings.

Comment: I use the command like `java -jar -Dlog4j.debug xxx.jar`.Is that right? But I found nothing about log4j.

Comment: I believe you should express that "java -Dlog4j.debug -jar xxx.jar".  If that doesn't help, try avoiding the jar packaging entirely, i.e. "java -Dlog4j.debug -cp xxx.jar com.plucury.App" and see if that differs from -jar behavior.

Comment: I extracted the jar and using "java -Dlog4j.debug xxx.App"(Without -cp because the dependency jars were extracted by maven plugin).But there isn't anything about log4j too.Then I switched my java env to Java6, and using the same command.The log4j works well again.

Comment: Might also be related to Maven then?  I don't think there's enough information to go on here.  I've poked around Google and I don't see any wealth of JDK7 + log4j issues.

The only other suggestion I can think of is to manually include the log4j jar yourself and manually initialize it from within your code.  That will at least tell you that log4j works at all.

Comment: I think I would use JDK6 at this moment.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the logging never came even though the entries were correct.  Later I discovered that one of the jar files (jxls-reader-0.9.6.jar) had a file log4j.xml and that was getting loaded first and used as log4j logging property file and hence we did not receive the logs.  I’ve removed the log4j.xml from the jar and it worked perfectly fine.

You may have similar problem, hope it may be similar solution.